# Stuck with the "old" Salesforce setup navigation menu - how do I get the new one?

Tags: setup, navigation, ui, menu

I'm stuck with the old navigation menu (on the left) in one org and have the new one (on the right) in most (if not all) of my other orgs. I remember some recent release notes talking about renaming **Administration Setup** to **Administer** - but when I tried to search for it I just couldn't find it. I have no idea whatsoever why I still have the old menu here - but it's rather annoying as I can't get really used to the new one if I always have the old one around here too.

Could anybody shed some light on this?

[image: Old Salesforce navigation menu]
[image: New Salesforce navigation menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the Improved User Interface at:
Customize> User Interface> and check "Enable Improved Setup User Interface".

Alternatively, you can search for "User Interface" in the quick find bar in Setup.

Comment: Wow. I have no idea how I could have missed this and why it wasn't enabled by default (like in all the other orgs) - thanks! If somebody has problems to find it - it's located under: Setup --> App Setup --> User Interface --> Setup --> Enable Improved Setup User Interface